# Type Arabic Urdu Hindi Text in Textbox Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, arabic

How can I type Arabic Urdu Hindi Textbox Directly Using Vb.net I have use the below code but not working:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", "ا")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("A", "آ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("b", "ب")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("B", "")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("c", "چ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("C", "ث")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("d", "د")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("D", "ډ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("e", "ع")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("E", "ږ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("f", "ف")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("F", "")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("G", "ګ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("g", "غ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("h", "ح")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("H", "ځ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("i", "ي")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("I", "ې")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("j", "ج")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("J", "ض")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("k", "ک")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("K", "خ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("l", "ل")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("L", "")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("m", "م")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("M", "")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("n", "ن")
 End Sub
```

Comment: If you go to settings and search for language there are several versions of Arabic available for keyboard input.

Comment: where is the setting dear tell me the place

Comment: I meant Windows settings. Right click on Start button and chose Settings.

Comment: dear i want to type direct in textbox i know about the windows keyboard

Comment: may be you can do it with keypress event, change each keychar as your above assignment, for example if e.keychar = "K" then e.keychar="خ".